# Query all addresses by postcode

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap

I need to get all addresses (on house number level) by their zip code - thought about OpenStreetMap but haven't found a way yet to achieve this. Their API can give me a feature of a zip code, but not the addresses in there, how to do this? 
I'm open for other web services as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it looks as still the best data available for that purpose will be the one offered by official/administrative sources.